# SVG AnimateTransform not working in Safari..?

Tags: svg-animate, smil, animatetransform, svg-transforms, svg-animationelements

Why is this animation, which works in FF and Chrome, not working in Safari (`begin="click"` does not trigger the animateTransform in Safari; replace `click` with for example 0s and you'll see it getting triggered)?

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" viewBox="0 0 1000 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="timeline-container">
      <rect id="project-10-activator" class="" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" width="20" height="20" x="11" y="142.2" transform="translate(-10,-10)" data-project-id="10" display="block">
        <animateTransform id="activate_project_10" begin="click" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></animateTransform>
        <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="inactivate_project_10.end" fill="freeze"></set>
        <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="activate_project_10.end" fill="freeze"></set>
      </rect>
      <rect id="project-10-inactivator" class="" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" width="20" height="20" x="11" y="142.2" transform="translate(-10,-10)" data-project-id="10" display="none">
        <animateTransform id="inactivate_project_10" begin="click" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></animateTransform>
        <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="activate_project_10.end" fill="freeze"></set>
        <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="inactivate_project_10.end" fill="freeze"></set>
      </rect>
      <text data-project-id="10" x="17" y="121.2" transform="rotate(-90,17,121.2)" class="timeline-project-label label-above-project-point">
        <tspan>Upper Title</tspan>
        <tspan class="project-name-span" x="17" dy="15">lower title</tspan>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="activate_project_10.begin" from="0 16.609375 139.7156219482422" to="90 16.609375 139.7156219482422" additive="sum" fill="freeze">
        </animateTransform>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="activate_project_10.begin" from="0 0" to="-33.140625 -10" additive="sum" fill="freeze"></animateTransform>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="inactivate_project_10.begin" from="0 0" to="33.140625 10" additive="sum" fill="freeze"></animateTransform>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="inactivate_project_10.begin" from="0 16.609375 139.7156219482422" to="-90 16.609375 139.7156219482422" additive="sum" fill="freeze">
        </animateTransform>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" repeatCount="1" dur="0.01s" from="-90 17 121.2" to="-90 17 121.2" fill="freeze" additive="replace" accumulate="sum" begin="inactivate_project_10.end"></animateTransform>
      </text>
    </svg>
```

Only when adding the following js :

```
document.getElementById( "project-10-activator" )
.addEventListener( "click", function() {

  document.getElementById( "activate_project_10" ).beginElement();

});

document.getElementById( "project-10-inactivator" )
.addEventListener( "click", function() {

  document.getElementById( "inactivate_project_10" ).beginElement();

});
```

The animation can be toggled on and off once, but then again fails. According to the specs, animateTransform should be supported in Safari (I guess I'll give up on using fakesmile to do this, so forget about IE..).

Any ideas for how to make this work in the same way for Safari as it's working in Chrome + FF??

***UPDATE***

Getting closer, but still not perfect (click on the rectangle multiple times, and you'll see that it's far from optimized)..... : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st3obn7m/1/)

The edits correspond to the addition of this script:

```
document.getElementById( "project-10-activator" )
.addEventListener( "click", function() {

// Reset the timer every time a new toggle cycle is initiated
document.getElementById( "timeline-container" ).setCurrentTime(0);

// Unpause the animation clock
document.getElementById( "timeline-container" ).unpauseAnimations();

  // Trigger the animations used to activate the label
  document.getElementById( "activate_project_10" ).beginElement();
  
  // Wait for the animation to complete + 100ms to account for delays, then
  // pause the animation clock
  window.setTimeout(function(){
  
  document.getElementById( "timeline-container" ).pauseAnimations();
  },600);

});

document.getElementById( "project-10-inactivator" )
.addEventListener( "click", function() {

// Unpause the animation clock
document.getElementById( "timeline-container" ).unpauseAnimations();

  // Start with the animations used to inactivate the label back to start
  document.getElementById( "inactivate_project_10" ).beginElement();
  
  // Wait for the reverse animation to complete, then again pause the animation clock
  window.setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById( "timeline-container" ).pauseAnimations();
  },600);
    

});
```

Maybe better to work with an event thats fired at the end of the animation, and then pause the animations. Is there such a thing? I'll keep digging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally got this SMIL - only solution, after going countless times through the docs. There's actually no need for a js polyfill using `beginElement()` for Safari; as the present solution works for all FF, Chrome and Safari, flawlessly:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" viewBox="0 0 1000 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="timeline-container">
      <rect id="activator_10" class="" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" width="20" height="20" x="11" y="142.2" transform="translate(-10,-10)" data-project-id="10" display="block">
        <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="inactivate_project_10.end" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></set>
        <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="activate_project_10.end" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></set>
      </rect>
      <rect id="inactivator_10" class="" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" width="20" height="20" x="11" y="142.2" transform="translate(-10,-10)" data-project-id="10" display="none">
        <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="activate_project_10.end" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></set>
        <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="inactivate_project_10.end" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"></set>
      </rect>
      <text data-project-id="10" x="17" y="121.2" transform="rotate(-90,17,121.2)" class="timeline-project-label label-above-project-point">
        <tspan>Upper Title</tspan>
        <tspan class="project-name-span" x="17" dy="15">lower title</tspan>
        <animateTransform id="activate_project_10" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="activator_10.click" from="0 16.609375 139.7156219482422" to="90 16.609375 139.7156219482422" additive="sum" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="activate_project_10.begin" from="0 0" to="-33.140625 -10" additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform id="inactivate_project_10" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="inactivator_10.click" from="0 0" to="33.140625 10" additive="sum" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" begin="inactivate_project_10.begin" from="0 16.609375 139.7156219482422" to="-90 16.609375 139.7156219482422" additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" repeatCount="1" dur="0.5s" from="-90 17 121.2" to="-90 17 121.2" fill="freeze" additive="replace" accumulate="sum" begin="inactivate_project_10.end"/>
      </text>
    </svg>
```

My Markup for the SMIL animations was actually not really proper, and FF and Chrome interestingly were still able to run the animations correctly, while Safari couldn't. You may compare the initial snippet of my question with the one in this answer to check the differences / problems; it was mainly about timing and when and how the different elements got triggered (`begin` attributes, etc.). No transformation x or y values were changed, was really all about how to code the different timings!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to write a proper polyfill solution for Safari (version 14), which including avoids that the animation gets triggered while it's already running:

```
// Initiate variable which keeps track if the concerned element is being
// animated or not.
var animActive = false;

document.getElementById("project-10-activator")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Only trigger animation if it is not currently running
    if (!animActive) {

      // Update the value of animActive, to indicate that this animation is
      // running
      animActive = true;

      // Reset animation clock back to 0
      document.getElementById("timeline-container").setCurrentTime(0);
      // Unpause the animation clock
      document.getElementById("timeline-container").unpauseAnimations();
      // Trigger the activation animation
      document.getElementById("activate_project_10").beginElement();
      // when the end of the last animation bound to that one is reached
      window.setTimeout(function() {

        // Pause the animation clock
        document.getElementById("timeline-container").pauseAnimations();
        // And reset the value of animActive
        animActive = false;

      }, 600);

    }

  });

document.getElementById("project-10-inactivator")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Also only trigger this animation if it is not already running
    if (!animActive) {

      // Update the value of animActive, to indicate that this animation is
      // running
      animActive = true;

      // Unpause the animation clock
      document.getElementById("timeline-container").unpauseAnimations();
      // Trigger the animation
      document.getElementById("inactivate_project_10").beginElement();

      // when the end of the last animation bound to that one is reached
      window.setTimeout(function() {

        // Pause the animation clock
        document.getElementById("timeline-container").pauseAnimations();
        // And reset the value of animActive
        animActive = false;

      }, 600);


    }

  });
```

Here the updated [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/2m5jzv91/).

Still, I wonder about the following:

A cleaner solution would be to use the element's (in this example for example the `activate_project_10` element's) [endEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement/endEvent_event). I.e. trigger the part of the `setTimeout`'s callback as the event listener of that event, for maximum timing precision.
But, even if I use exactly the same code as the one in the link above to register an `endEvent` listener, it gets fired in FF and Chrome, but again Safari does not even fire the `endEvent`, although the element animates. Why that..?

***NOTE***

This polyfill is intended only for Safari; it does not work for example in FF; where it can be simply omitted (and the `begin` attributes of the two main animation elements need to be set back to `click`). Still interested in a much more generic solution than this...